# When (and why) implicit (automatic) Dependency Injection sometimes not available in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

Implicit Constructor and Function Dependency Injection (DI) in .NET 7... as shown in this [.NET documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection) is not always possible in its simplest (desired) form. However, it is not clear to me where (and why) this is the case. Also, if I do require the service provider to explicitly inject into a constructor or function, is this (service collection) provider available in .NET without defining and setting a global property myself?

For example, I see in many .NET samples ([such as this one](https://github.com/IEvangelist/azure-cosmos-dotnet-repository/blob/e362123056521262171b3c6a0b1fdbd0333a7c77/samples/Microsoft.Azure.CosmosRepository/ServiceTier/Program.cs#L45C31-L45C31)), that a service provider is explicitly required in a standard situation to inject the object as:

Add to DI service collection:

```
        .AddSingleton<IExampleService, ExampleService>()).Build();
```

Declare a function with DI:

```
static async Task ServiceExampleAsync(IExampleService service) {...}
```

Call:

```
await ServiceExampleAsync(host.Services.GetService<IExampleService>()!);
```

So, when does constructor injection work in its purest form in .NET [like here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection) and when do I have to use the (less desirable) explicit injection approach as shown above? How do I know? If I need the explicit injection, can I get the host (as above) or provider in a .NET code tree without having to declare a global class/property myself in program.cs (for example)?

Any pointers, tips, helpful middleware appreciated. I've already searched & read here and elsewhere.

Comment: If you follow the practices you won't face such a scenario. The example you share is trying to demonstrate some other things in a console application, not the DI practices.

Comment: Thanks Edlar, I've observed these technique being used in many places, so if it always worked "following the practices" it begs the question: why here (and others ) are not able to just use the simple practice always? That is my question: what is the difference. I've also observed places where I can't get those practices you refer to to work. Not that I'm an expert, but I'd still like to understand. Simple pointer to those practices you mean? Thanks

Comment: Well, Microsoft has its own guidelines for default DI provider. And there is a section where you may want to look at the other DI providers. [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines#default-service-container-replacement).

Comment: Thanks for this good reference. I'm liking "Injection based on name" a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I have now found the answer that I needed, and a few very helpful insights in addition.

The answer/clue I needed: Classes or functions that require DI must themselves be registered in the service collection. Here is the key quote from [this](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/aspnet-core-dependency-injection-what-is-the-iserviceprovider-and-how-is-it-built) article:

> These instances can be injected into other services resolved from the same dependency injection container.

So the unsightly explicit injections that are also very common in test code are to avoid having to register the entire dependency tree in a service collection just for the one-shot use of a single test function or class.

Helpful references:

- https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/category/asp-net-core/dependency-injection
- https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/aspnet-core-dependency-injection-what-is-the-iserviceprovider-and-how-is-it-built